# How can I reference a dynamically changing array index inside a parallel command in bash

Tags: bash, parallel-processing

I'm writing a parallel command in bash and need to give an array element, whose index changes with the job number of the parallel job execution, as an argument.

I tried using the variable $PARALLEL_SEQ, but I cannot get the syntax to work.

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

test_array=(apple orange lemon mango banana)
seq 5 | parallel echo ${test_array[$PARALLEL_SEQ]}
```

I expect the second argument after parallel to be evaluated with a string as a result(like 'orange' for the second parallel execution). 
I want my code to print:

```
apple
orange
lemon
mango
banana
```

and not:

```
apple 1
apple 2
apple 3
apple 4
apple 5
```

Answer (score 0):

from your command PARALLEL_SEQ is expanded by th shell before calling parallel.

from documentation

> However, when you want to use a shell variable you need to quote the $-sign. Here is an example using $PARALLEL_SEQ. This variable is set by GNU parallel itself, so the evaluation of the $ must be done by the sub shell started by GNU parallel:
>
> ```
> seq 10 | parallel -N2 echo seq:\$PARALLEL_SEQ arg1:{1} arg2:{2}
> ```

After comment I could find cygwin with parallel, and could test following commands, which worked:

```
foo(){ test_array=(apple orange lemon mango banana);}
export -f foo
seq 5 | parallel 'foo && echo "${test_array[PARALLEL_SEQ-1]}" && : '
```

workaround due to arrays can't be exported through environment

the `:` at the end is a no-op command so that last argument passed by parallel is not taken as an argument for echo command.

Comment: I do not see directly how it could resolve my problem with printing out the correct value out of the array. Could you clarify how I can achieve the intended output? Note that the order of the printed elements could be different because the commands run in parallel. 
Thanks in advance.

Comment: i couldn't test because i don't have an environment with parallel installed but you may have to export array (or maybe just use it directly because subshell can see unexported variables) but you need to escape `$` to prevent current shell to expand it before parallel can see them. Maybe just using single quotes `echo '${test_array[$PARALLEL_SEQ]}'`

Answer (score 0):

`env_parallel` is made for you:

```
# Ignore all variables set now
env_parallel --start
# Introduce a new variable
test_array=(apple orange lemon mango banana)
# Copy that variable to the environment of the command
seq 5 | env_parallel echo '${test_array[{= $_=seq() -1 =}]}'
```

It even works on remote systems:

```
# Copy that variable to the environment of the command on the remote server
seq 5 | env_parallel -S server echo '${test_array[{= $_=seq() -1 =}]}'
```

You will need a fairly new version of GNU Parallel for that to work though.